# How to stop Youtube embed from playing in the background when I'm switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is the situation, I have 3 tabs and each tab have Youtube embed. When I play the video in any tabs then switch/click to the other tabs the video wont stop playing in the background. Basically I want the video to stop when I'm switching tabs.

See the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/ event types: `show.bs.tab`, `shown.bs.tab`, `hide.bs.tab`, `hidden.bs.tab`.

Below is my code and you can also check it here [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/mdLYyZv)

```js
$('[data-toggle="pill"]').on('hidden.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var myTarget = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
  $(myTarget).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
  $(myTarget).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
  console.log($(myTarget))
});
```

```html
<!--tab contents-->
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-latest-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-latest-1-tab">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
         <div class="col-lg-5 my-4">
            <div class="pb-3 h3">Title 1</div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-7 px-0 px-lg-3">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VszEg4XAbgk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-latest-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-latest-2-tab">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
         <div class="col-lg-5 my-4">
            <div class="pb-3 h3">Title 2</div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-7 px-0 px-lg-3">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
               <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LAr6oAKieHk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-latest-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-latest-3-tab">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
         <div class="col-lg-5 my-4">
            <div class="pb-3 h3">Title 3</div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-7 px-0 px-lg-3">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rn6XbqBmQ58" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--tab lists-->
<ul class="row nav nav-pills nav-fill  p-0 m-0" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-latest-1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-latest-1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-latest-1" aria-selected="true">
      Title 1
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-latest-2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-latest-2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-latest-2" aria-selected="false">
      Title 2
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-latest-3-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-latest-3" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-latest-3" aria-selected="false">
      Title 3
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: play() and pause() are available on HTML video element. You can target the video element and call those. But, since you're using YouTube videos, you might run into CORS issues.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the `a` element, and the target should be `e.target`

```js
$('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('hidden.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var myTarget = $(e.target).attr('href');
  let src = $(myTarget).find('iframe').attr('src'); 
  $(myTarget).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
  
  $(myTarget).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
  console.log($(myTarget))
});
```